# Microsoft Threads, setting Security and Access Rights

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading

I am trying to make a basic thread manager. You may have seen one of my previous questions where I posed some bad code, and I am still working on that code! But I am stuck because I want to be able to call the function GetExitCodeThread(HANDLE, LPDWORD), but I am having trouble implementing this. The first problem I ran into I think I figured out what I need to do, but I don't know how to implement it. I was originally calling CreateThread with the security attributes set to NULL, and from the looks of it I need to set it to THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, however I don't know how to fill the LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure it wants. The structure from msdn is:

```
typedef struct _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {
  DWORD  nLength;
  LPVOID lpSecurityDescriptor;
  BOOL   bInheritHandle;
} SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *PSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, *LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
```

But I don't know how to fill that with THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, and I don't understand what I fill the other parts of the structure with.

I think if I set the security attributes of creating the thread, I should be able to call GetExitCodeThread, and then my code should work... Does anyone have any example code of setting the security attributes while creating a thread that I could look and reference off of? And any recommendation on understanding the windows library better?

Comment: I figured out how to make this work, and I actually did not need the security_attributes struct. However, I would still like more information on how to use it, and I am confused on the msdn's website's description. SO any clarification would be nice!

Comment: Please use `_beginthreadex` instead of `CreateThread`.

Comment: Why is it better to use _beginthreadex instead of CreateThread?

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx): "A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management rather than `CreateThread` and `ExitThread`; this requires the use of the multithreaded version of the CRT. If a thread created using `CreateThread` calls the CRT, the CRT may terminate the process in low-memory conditions." --- Also, using `_beginthreadex` allows you to use the thread handle to wait on thread exit.  You must close the handle yourself.

Comment: @paddy "*Also, using `_beginthreadex` allows you to use the thread handle to wait on thread exit. You must close the handle yourself*" - the same is true when calling `CreateThread`, too. So the only argument for `_beginthreadex` vs `CreateThread` is the CRT requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The `lpThreadAttributes` argument determines whether the handle is inheritable and what security permissions are set on the thread object.  It does not affect the security access granted to the handle returned by `CreateThread`, which is always `THREAD_ALL_ACCESS`.

Similarly, the handle returned when the new thread itself calls `GetCurrentThread` always has full access rights, except on older out-of-support versions of Windows.

If you were to use `OpenThread` later on to get an additional handle, or if an external process tried to use `OpenThread` to get a handle, that is when the thread security permissions would come into play.

On supported versions of Windows, the default security permissions for the thread object are (almost?) always appropriate, so either `lpThreadAttributes` or `lpSecurityDescriptor` should be `NULL`.  Software dealing with cryptography, authentication, or other especially sensitive tasks might on rare occasions use non-default thread security permissions.  (I can't think of any useful purpose this would serve, but there may be some oddball cases where it is appropriate.)

On older versions of Windows it might be necessary to specify `lpSecurityDescriptor` if the thread calling `CreateThread` is impersonating another user, although the recommended practice is to cease impersonation before calling `CreateThread`.

This is all detailed in the [MSDN documentation for `CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).