# How could I set thread access rights in windows with C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

According to MS documentation, a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES is required. And I looked at the example on [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--)

But I don't really get it.

I just want to have a handle, which is returned by _beginthreadex, to have the THREAD_SET_CONTEXT right, so that QueueUserAPC will work.

Comment: Did you try reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248300/microsoft-threads-setting-security-and-access-rights)?

Comment: Did you just try using `QueueUserAPC`?  The main handle to the thread, that comes from thread creation, should have full rights already.

Comment: The handle returned by `CreateThread()` should already have `THREAD_SET_CONTEXT` enabled on it, so you should be able to just use `QueueUserAPC()` "out of the box" without doing anything special to enable it..